# Turning off the wi-fi functionality of a Netgear WNR2000

Tags: wireless-networking

My school has set up a ton of wireless access points and now they want me to turn off the wireless functionality of on my router.  I have a Netgear WNR2000 and I can't find the option to turn off the wireless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the left hand side, under the Advanced heading is a link labeled Wireless Settings.  In that menu is a check box labeled "Enable Wireless Router Radio".  Uncheck that and the wireless signal will be turned off.

Answer (score 2):

A quick review of [the manual](ftp://downloads.netgear.com/files/WNR2000v2_SM_01SEP2009.pdf) shows a physical switch for the wireless (see page 5).  Have you tried that?

Comment: That would be great, except I have version 1 of the router, not version 2.  Unfortunately, version 1 does not have the button.

Comment: Always useful to post that kind of information in the original question ;)